# How to disable -Werror=date-time/macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds

Tags: drivers, compiling, gcc

I am trying to compile a driver for a Netis WF2190 adapter.
Yes, I just downloaded the latest from them.

How can I disable the `-Werror=date-time` in the build?  I can't find it anywhere in the build script so I figure it must be some global default setting.  Clearly the code is just trying to embed the build date/time into the output, so there should be no problem with disabling this warning.

Here are some of the warnings I'm getting that are being treated as errors:

```
/home/andy/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
/home/andy/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: The `date-time` warning is new in gcc 4.9 I think - it is possibly turned on implicitly by `-Wall`  (and turned into an error implicitly by `-Werror`). You could try turning it **off** explicitly using the `-Wno-` form i.e. `-Wno-error=date-time` added to the `CFLAGS` but I'm guessing and can't test it.

Comment: @steeldriver yes, that worked, thank you!  You are welcome to submit it as an answer and I will accept it.  The other part of the problem was I didn't realize the install script was re-extracting the source every time and overwriting changes I made to the makefile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The date-time warning is new in gcc 4.9 I think - it is possibly turned on implicitly by `-Wall` (and turned into an error implicitly by `-Werror`).

You could try turning it off explicitly using the `-Wno-` form i.e. by adding

```
-Wno-error=date-time
```

to the `CFLAGS`.

Comment: What, specifically, does one need to type into the terminal to do this?

Comment: Hi @steeldriver
Is this the correct syntax:
CFLAGS += "-Wno-error=date-time "

Comment: On newer versions of gcc (mine is 12.2.0) modifying CFLAGS in the makefile is not allowed. Instead the syntax would be: ```ccflags-y += "-Wno-error=date-time"``` The compiler warns of this

Answer (score 3):

I tried quite a few times adding the "Wno-error=date-time" line to the CFLAGS, but it didn't seem to work.

The easiest solution by far for me was to find the file that was producing the "__DATE__" line by executing

```
grep -r "__DATE__"
```

which (for the source code that I'm working with) gave me the file

```
acore/info.patch:+          "Compiled on " __DATE__ " for kernel %s"
```

I simply changed this to a string without the variable by removing the quotation marks, i.e.

```
"Compiled on __DATE__ for kernel %s"
```

The compilation was then able to proceed

**EDIT:** As mentioned before, use `make clean` before running configure and make, or even better, extract a fresh version from the zip/tar file

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to remove the offending macro by deleting line 66 from the rtw_debug.c file.

```
sed -i -e '66d' /home/andy/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_debug.c
```

Now you can continue with the build:

```
cd /home/andy/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/
sudo make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: sudo make clean is important