# How Do I Fix No Sound On Ubuntu 17.04 64bit

Tags: drivers, sound, realtek

I have recently switched over to Linux and decided to use the Ubuntu distro version 17.04 . After installation was done I realized that I had no audio and soon after realized that my motherboard does not support Linux which is the reason I want to install a sound driver manually. After I downloaded the Realtek Audio driver ( Linux Driver 3.0 ) I had difficulty installing the driver since the installation instruction did not work. So how do I do it?
The results of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` is :

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio



        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8724

        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 133

        Memory at df240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

        Memory at df220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]

        Capabilities: <access denied>

        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

When attempted to install file through terminal using the commands given by an answer below, after the command line `make` the following error was given :

```
error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
       "Compiled on " __DATE__ " for kernel %s"
```

And on the last line it said :

```
Makefile:167: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

After the command line `make install` another error was given which was :

```
Makefile:188: recipe for target 'install-headers' failed
make: *** [install-headers] Error 1
```

I would also like to point out that after entering `make install` all the lines either started with :

```
rm: cannot remove '/ A FILE LOCATION ' : permission denied
```

or they started with :

```
install: cannot create regular file `/ A FILE LOCATION ' : permission denied
```

The results of `sudo lshw | grep -A5 core` was :

```
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: PRIME Z270-A
   vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
   physical id: 0
   version: Rev 1.xx
--
      configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
--
      configuration: driver=skl_uncore
      resources: irq:0
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: HD Graphics 530
         vendor: Intel Corporation
```

The error given after using `sudo make install` using the method in the answer below was :

```
Makefile:206: recipe for target 'install-modules' failed
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
```

Comment: can you provide the link of file you have downloaded ??

Comment: http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false                                       This is the link of the website and I downloaded the Linux Driver version 3.0 which is in the bottom of the page.

Comment: What is your motherboard and sound card model ??

Comment: As for the exact model of sound card I am not sure how to find it but my motherboard is an ASUS PRIME Z270-A. ( the sound card was already installed on the motherboard )

Comment: I used the command line ` lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio" ` hopefully it provides the needed information about the sound card. I will edit the results in the description of the question above.

Comment: None of your output indicates the existence of a Realtek chip, although the specs of the motherboard you say you have (ASUS PRIME Z270-A) indicate that it should have a Realtek® ALC S1220A. This doesn't parse for me. Perhaps the output of `sudo lshw | grep -A5 core` can clarify which board you actually have. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I added the results of ` sudo lshw | grep -A5 core ` to the end of the description above.

Answer (score 2):

Try these

```
    tar -xvf 0001-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8.tar.bz2
    cd Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/
    tar -xvf alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8.tar.bz2
    cd alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/
    sudo apt install gcc g++ build-essential patch
    ./configure --with-cards=hda-intel
    make
    sudo make install
```

Then reboot computer

If you encounter any error, please post that error as code in the end of your question.

**Update 1**

Related to

> > When attempted to install file through terminal using the commands given by an answer below, after the command line make the following error was given :
> >
> > > error: macro "**DATE**" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
> > >              "Compiled on " **DATE** " for kernel %s"

Try Solutions from

[How to disable -Werror=date-time/macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593566/how-to-disable-werror-date-time-macro-date-might-prevent-reproducible-bui)

And you can't do `make install` without successful `make` and without superuser permissions. try `sudo make install`. (i have a habit of doing most of admin work from root shell)

**Update 2**

Also try these with sudo

```
sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel
sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel probe_mask=0x1ff
```

from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373777/realtek-alc1220-audio-chipset-on-linux-mint-18-1

Comment: That should be `sudo make install`.

Comment: I added the given error after using  ` sudo make install `  in the description

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 I checked the links but I could not figure out what to look for when used the command lines given or when to use the "update 2 " command lines. I only entered the command lines from the home directory which returned a few lines ending in " no such file or directory ". how do I get the `make` command line to work.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
killall unity-panel-service
killall gnome-panel
```

You can also try the following commands to bring back the sound indicator in the Panel bar:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound
sudo apt-get install indicator-messages
sudo apt-get install evolution-indicator
```

I had success from here "http://sourcedigit.com/20436-sound-icon-missing-ubuntu-how-to-fix-sound-problem-in-ubuntu/" (I hope you too).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I installed Ubuntu 17.10 64bit twice. The first time after struggling a lot I found the solution that worked both the times. 
My solution was to use pavucontrol.
Install it using : sudo apt install pavucontrol .
Then run pavucontrol and click on the > sign at the top right till you come to the "Configuration" tab. Select the profile "Analog Stereo Duplex (unplugged)" for Built-in Audio.