# How To Fix Error -Werror=date-time/macro “__DATE__” might prevent reproducible builds

Tags: drivers, software-installation, realtek

So I have been trying to install Realtek Audio Drivers but after `make install` I get :

> -Werror=date-time/macro “**DATE**” might prevent reproducible builds

I saw a post with a similar issue but I did not understand what to exactly type in the terminal. The post had said that I should add `-Wno-error=date-time` to `CFLAGS` which I do not how to do. I will link the post below.

[How to disable -Werror=date-time/macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593566/how-to-disable-werror-date-time-macro-date-might-prevent-reproducible-bui)

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 64bit.

Also please do not post as replicate since the other posts did not help me and I cannot comment on them due to lack of privilege points.

Results of `sudo lshw -C sound`

```
  *-multimedia              
      description: Audio device
      product: 200 Series PCH HD Audio
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 1f.3
      bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
      version: 00
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
      configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
      resources: irq:133 memory:df240000-df243fff memory:df220000-df22ffff
```

`pavucontrol` and `alsamixer` results are linked below respectively :
[image]
[image]

Comment: @steeldriver for both of them it gave the error                                                                                     `   make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.   `

Answer (score 3):

Edit your source code `Makefile` and add this near the top of the file (if you look closely, this line may already be there, but just commented out):

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=date-time
```

Then do your normal `./configure` (if required) and `make` and `sudo make install`.

**Update #1:**

If the source code that you're using is from http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false then they're only for kernels 2.x and 3.x, and as such, won't compile on current versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: After adding the line to the makefile source code the same error was given.

Comment: Is there any other driver to install for Ubuntu 17.04 since I had no audio when I installed Linux.

Comment: What make/model computer? Show me `sudo lshw -C sound`.

Comment: I added the results at the end of the description.

Comment: Ubuntu is seeing the audio board. Are you sure that the audio isn't muted, or volume set way low? Check your Sound panel in System Settings. In `terminal` type `alsamixer` and make sure nothing is muted. Install `pavucontrol` and also make sure nothing is muted.

Comment: I installed pavucontrol using `  sudo apt-get install pavucontrol ` and checked for results. They are added at the end of the description.

Comment: In pavucontrol, change the port from S/PDIF to something else, retest sound.

Comment: S/PDIF is the only port showing. I re-added the picture with the advanced options of pavucontrol in the description.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have any more ideas for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [these drivers](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) then it's not that simple.

It's the kernel build scripts that enforce this logic and the error flag is added after any normal means of injecting the no-error counterpart. Thus, the error remains.

The only fix I see is temporarily remove that line from the kernel build makefile:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/date-time/d' /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-32/Makefile
```

However, that gets you only to the next problem:

> implicit declaration of function ‘do_posix_clock_monotonic_gettime’

Which is a real problem caused by aging unmaintained source.

After this experiment, make sure you restore the original Makefile:

```
 sudo mv /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-32/Makefile.bak \
     /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-32/Makefile
```

Comment: My fix doesn't modify system source, it's only required for compile errors on gcc 4.9 and later.

Comment: @Melvyn after using the first command line it gave the error `  sed: can't read /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-32/Makefile: No such file or directory  ` ( I thought u meant the line is in the kernel makefile but it was not there either ) .